# How can I export an object declared in a .ejs file to my index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, iot

I have a script inside of my .ejs file, the script is very simple, I'm just grabbing the input data from the user and putting inside an object. So, what I want to do is to send this object to my index.js and in my index.js I'm gonna use the data from my object to use in a node module called coap (is very simular to http), but I don't really know how to send my object form a .ejs file to my index.js file which I'm using the express module.

```
const btnSubmitData = document.getElementById("btnSubmitData")
btnSubmitData.addEventListener("click", () => {

    const boardIP = document.getElementById("BoardInputIP").value
    const boardMethod = document.querySelector('input[name="inlineRadioOptions"]:checked').value
    const boardFunction = document.getElementById("selectFunction").value
    const boardPoint = document.getElementById("selectPoint").value

    const inputDataBoard = {
        ipBoard: boardIP,
        methodCoapBoard: boardMethod,
        functionBoard: boardFunction, 
        pointBoard: boardPoint
    }


    })
```

Answer (score 0):

don't you have to use ejs  to display  - not index.js?